# How can I set Thunderbird to use "Reader's default colors (Don't set colors in page)" by default?

Tags: email, thunderbird, html, colors

Personally my color preference for email messages (and most other windows) is a dark background with a light foreground, but others may like/need different color settings. I can format the messages I send to let the recipient's email client choose the color settings (`Format` -> `Page Colors and Background` and select `Reader's default colors (Don't set colors in page)`) and this does what I want it to do, but I have to set this every time I want to send a message.

I can get around this by de-selecting `Compose messages in HTML format` in the account's `Composition & Addressing` settings, but this disables the use of HTML in composition and I have other components (usually tables) in the messages that I would prefer to use HTML for.

How can I set Thunderbird to always use `Reader's default colors (Don't set colors in page)` instead of setting custom colors in an HTML message? An account-specific setting would be preferred, but a global setting would also be useful. I can't seem to find a setting for this in the Thunderbird `Config Editor`.

Forcing recipients to override pre-defined colors on incoming messages is not a feasible option, especially in enterprise environments.

I am using the latest Thunderbird beta (33.0) on Xubuntu 14.04.1 LTS (trusty).

Comment: This issue has existed for as long as I can remember. I [asked this on mozillazine](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=39&t=2166581) in 2011.

At least somebody has filed a [Bugzilla report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=690644).

Comment: And 3 years later, I have [created a patch](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=690644).